# Android Wear complication update behaviour

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, android-wear-complication

Im trying to program complication service in Android Wear based using the [RandomNumberProviderService](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/watchface/provider/RandomNumberProviderService.java) as guide but im having trouble coming out with a way of separating the behaviour when I tap the complication and when I only need to update the info programatically (when the watch recieves a DataApi change).
Tapping the complication should send a Message to the handheld, and it does now but I have no way of only updating the info on the complication.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [ComplicationSimpleWatchFaceService](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace/blob/1abef60b07f1710540173b76b327951fc49b3bde/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/watchface/ComplicationSimpleWatchFaceService.java):

```
        /*
         * Called when there is updated data for a complication id.
         */
        @Override
        public void onComplicationDataUpdate(
                int complicationId, ComplicationData complicationData) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplicationDataUpdate() id: " + complicationId);

            // Adds/updates active complication data in the array.
            mActiveComplicationDataSparseArray.put(complicationId, complicationData);
            invalidate();
        }
```

According to the [Receiving data and rendering complications](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/complications.html#adding_complications_to_a_watch_face) documentation:

> To start receiving complication data, a watch face calls `setActiveComplications`, in the `WatchFaceService.Engine class`, with a list of watch face complication IDs. A watch face creates these IDs to uniquely identify slots on the watch face where complications can appear, and passes them to the **`createProviderChooserIntent`** method to allow the user to decide which complication should go in which slot.
>
> Complication data is delivered via the onComplicationDataUpdate (of `WatchFaceService.Engine`) callback.

Kindly check the [Android WatchFace Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace) the link you've provided is part of this example), this demonstrates how to create watch faces for android wear and includes a phone app and a wearable app. The wearable app has a variety of watch faces including analog, digital, opengl, calendar, steps, interactive, etc.

Hope this helps.